# "The process cannot access the file XXXX because it is being used by another process" after having been used by file.copy

Tags: c#, file, process

I am currently working on a project where the goal is to sort some file (Image files, but might be others in the future)
My current problem lies in the fact that after a file goes through the following piece of code it gets stuck and the File.delete and File.Move that's used later on can't do their operations on the file.

So far I've gone through quite a few posts here on stack overflow, which have had be fiddling with the Filestream Parameters, Garbage Collecting and using .Close() and .Dispose() inside using just incase.

```
public void CopyFile(string source, string destination)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        try
        {
            using (imgShare)
            {
                using (netConn)
                {
                    var sourcePath = $"{imgShare.GetFolderPath(Folder.Storage)}\\Item\\";
                    var oldFile = $"{sourcePath}{source}";
                    var tmpFileName = $"{sourcePath}{destination}";
                }
            }
            GC.Collect();
            using (imgShareLegacy)
            {
                using (netConnLegacy)
                {
                    var sourcePath = $"{imgShareLegacy.GetFolderPath(Folder.Storage)}\\item\\";
                    var oldFile = $"{sourcePath}{source}";
                    var tmpFileName = $"{sourcePath}{destination}";
                    CopyFiles(oldFile, tmpFileName);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"ERROR OCCURRED AT {DateTime.Now.ToString("T")} inside CopyFile: {ex} | EX-MESSAGE: {ex.Message} | SOURCE: {source} | DEST: {destination}");
        }
    }

    private void CopyFiles(string oldFile, string tmpFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(oldFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                File.Copy(fs.Name, tmpFileName, true);
                File.SetAttributes(tmpFileName, FileAttributes.Normal);
                fs.Dispose(); 
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"ERROR OCCURRED AT {DateTime.Now.ToString("T")} inside CopyFile: {ex} | EX-MESSAGE: {ex.Message} | OLDFILE: {oldFile} | TMPFILENAME: {tmpFileName}");
        }
    }
```

I apologize for the code being as messy as it is, I've been trying a few different things to get this to work. The latest being splitting the code up, with the smallest hope it might have worked.

The Error is thrown inside the DeleteFile Method when it is called right after the CopyFile method and looks like this:

```
public void PromoteTempFile(IEnumerable<ImgNameChanges> tmpNameChanges)
    {
        var nameChanges = tmpNameChanges.ToArray();

        try
        {             
                    var sourcePath = $"{imgShare.GetFolderPath(Folder.Storage)}\\item\\";
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                    for (int i = 0; i < tmpNameChanges.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        var oldFile = $"{sourcePath}{nameChanges[i].OldVal}";
                        DeleteFile(oldFile, imgShare, netConn);
                    }
                    GC.Collect();
                    for (int i = 0; i < tmpNameChanges.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        var tmpFile = $"{sourcePath}{nameChanges[i].NewVal}";
                        MoveFile(tmpFile, imgShare, netConn);
                    var sourcePathLegacy = $"{imgShareLegacy.GetFolderPath(Folder.Storage)}\\item\\";

                    for (int i = 0; i < tmpNameChanges.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        GC.Collect();
                        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                        var oldFile = $"{sourcePathLegacy}{nameChanges[i].OldVal}";
                        DeleteFile(oldFile, imgShareLegacy, netConnLegacy);

                    }
                    GC.Collect();
                    for (int i = 0; i < tmpNameChanges.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        var tmpFile = $"{sourcePathLegacy}{nameChanges[i].NewVal}";
                        MoveFile(tmpFile, imgShareLegacy, netConnLegacy);                          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Debug.WriteLine($"ERROR OCCURRED AT {DateTime.Now.ToString("T")} inside PromoteToFile: {ex} | EX-MESSAGE: {ex.Message} | TMPFILE: {tmpNameChanges}");
        }
    }

    private void MoveFile(string tmpFile, ThgEasyImageShareAccess imgAccess, NetworkConnection netConn)
    {
        var errCount = 0;
        while (errCount <= 1)
        {
            try
            {
                using (imgAccess)
                {
                    using (netConn)
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete))
                        {
                            File.Move(fs.Name, fs.Name.Replace("tmp_", string.Empty));
                            fs.Dispose();
                            fs.Close();
                            errCount = 5;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"ERROR OCCURRED AT {DateTime.Now.ToString("T")} inside MoveFile: {ex} | EX-MESSAGE: {ex.Message} | TMPFILE: {tmpFile} | IMG ACCESS: {imgAccess} | NETCONN: {netConn}");
                errCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    private void DeleteFile(string oldFile, ThgEasyImageShareAccess imgAccess, NetworkConnection netConn)
    {
        // At loope de filer der sidder fast igennem, virker ikke da de stadig sidder fast bagefter
        var errCount = 0;

        while (errCount <= 1)
        {
            try
            {
                using (imgAccess)
                {
                    using (netConn)
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(oldFile, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete))
                        {
                            if (File.Exists(fs.Name))
                            {
                                File.Delete(fs.Name);
                            }
                            fs.Dispose();
                            fs.Close();
                            errCount = 5;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               Debug.WriteLine($"ERROR OCCURRED AT {DateTime.Now.ToString("T")} inside DeleteFile: {ex} | EX-MESSAGE: {ex.Message} | OLDFILE: {oldFile} | IMGACCESS: {imgAccess} | NETCONN: {netConn}");
                errCount++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The ImgShare and Netconn
are two global variables created when the files is used and disposed when it is no longer in use.

```
private ThgEasyImageShareAccess imgShare;
    private NetworkConnection netConn;

    private ThgEasyImageShareAccess imgShareLegacy;
    private NetworkConnection netConnLegacy; 

    public ImageRepository()
    {
        imgShare = new ThgEasyImageShareAccess(SourceName.MedieServer);
        netConn = new NetworkConnection(imgShare.GetFolderPath(Folder.Storage), new NetworkCredential(imgShare.Username, imgShare.Password, imgShare.Domain));
        imgShareLegacy = new ThgEasyImageShareAccess(SourceName.MedieServerLegacy);
        netConnLegacy = new NetworkConnection(imgShareLegacy.GetFolderPath(Folder.Storage), new NetworkCredential(imgShareLegacy.Username, imgShareLegacy.Password, imgShareLegacy.Domain));
    }

    ~ImageRepository()  
    {
        imgShare.Dispose();
        netConn.Dispose();
        imgShareLegacy.Dispose();
        netConnLegacy.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: why are you using a stream to copy the file? file.copy("old","new") wlll copy the file for you

Comment: It was added to have the ability to use the using in an attempt to make sure the files was disposed of. After the operation had been done with it.

Comment: Well really messy...Opening Stream (which will raise exception if file not fount), then checking if file exists, then deleting it. Why you even open stream? Do you really need so much `GC.Collect()` calls? All those using's, do you really need all of them? using on `NetworkConnection` probably closes at the end.

Comment: Yeah I know its messy, its slowly been building up over the last.. Week or two while I've been trying different things to fix the issue. And now I most likely do not need that much GC but I'd gotten quite desperate in terms of finding a solution. The stream was started with the hopes of being able to dispose of the files after use to fix the errors in the beginning when I started seeing the problem.

Comment: Original code would be much clear to understand, now it's mess and creates more unnecessary questions.

Comment: Sadly I don't have the original code anymore

Comment: Start by removing all that `GC.Collect()` nonsense. Then close this project and create a new [mcve].

Comment: I suggest you to use some sort of Git in the future so that you can push your code into a repository. Then you will always have access to an uncountable number of versions of your code. Perfect for stepping back if you did some mistakes.